# Bad sound quality through headphones with Dell Precision 5570 laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

I was hearing flat, tinny, poor-bass, just terrible sound quality, after switching to a new Dell Precision 5570 workstation with Windows 10 64-bit. I use Jabra Evolve2 40 headphones that plug directly into the thunderbolt/USB-C port on the laptop. The same headphones sounded much better with my old Lenovo laptop. I also began having seemingly random fluctuations in volume even though I hadn't touched the volume slider. Also the bass/treble level adjustments in my headphone's software were having no effect.

I had tried updating the Realtek audio driver, updating the software for my headphones, and disabling audio enhancements in Windows sound settings for the headphone device... with no/little difference from any of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue. I disabled "Intel Smart Sound Technology for USB Audio" in the Windows Device Manager, and after restarting I had instantly better sound. Now I finally have full rich bass again, and I can adjust the bass/treble as I wish through the Jabra headphone software.

[image: how to disable Intel Smart Sound Technology for USB Audio]

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me, but changing the driver to Microsoft one did it:
https://superuser.com/questions/1363052/dell-xps-13-poor-aux-sound-quality/1363056#1363056